# User control with custom properties like Grid.ColumnDefinitions

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am creating a user control and I want to add some custom properties.

This property can receive an N number of children. It would look something like Grid.ColumnDefinitions.

```xml
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

So I would like my user control to be that way

```xml
<MyUserControl>
        <MyUserControl.MyCustomProperty>
            <Item Attribute="A" AnotherAttribute="Foo"  />
            <Item Attribute="B" AnotherAttribute="Bar"  />
            <Item Attribute="C" AnotherAttribute="Test"  />
        </MyUserControl.MyCustomProperty>
</MyUserControl>
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to do this.

Is there a name for these types of properties? Where can I find an example of how to create them?

Comment: Grid's property is called `ColumnDefinitions`. it is well, a *property*, which has collection type. `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` is a XAML tag syntax of writing properties. Any property can be written like that. Looks like you need collection property, so take a look at ItemsControl `ItemsSource` / `Items` property and do the same with MyCustomProperty

Comment: Maybe you could even simply derive your control from ItemsControl instead of UserControl.

Comment: Just declare a property of the appropriate type. Don't forget that the _collection_ itself needs to be initialized, so that the runtime can then _add_ the individual elements when it loads the XAML. See duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Define a read-only [collection-type dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/collection-type-dependency-properties?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        SetValue(MyCustomPropertyKey, new List<Item>());
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey MyCustomPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
          nameof(MyCustomProperty),
          typeof(List<Item>),
          typeof(MyUserControl), 
          new PropertyMetadata()
        );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomerPropertyProperty =
        MyCustomPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public List<Item> MyCustomProperty =>
        (List<Item>)GetValue(MyCustomerPropertyProperty);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work as I expected. List <Item> is a list of other controls, and they were not displayed in preview or runtime. I think I need to study more WPF to do this.

Comment: @FelipeGodinho: If they weren't display at runtime you did something wrong. Try to copy and paste my class into your solution and then use your XAML...

Comment: I managed to get them to be displayed by adding an ItemsControl in the XAML of MyUserControl, and linking ItemsControl.ItemsSource to MyCustomProperty (List <Item>). I don't know if that would be the right way.

Comment: In my example, there is a `MyCustomProperty` to which you can add `Item` elements directly like this: `<MyUserControl.MyCustomProperty><Item Attribute="A" AnotherAttribute="Foo"  /></MyUserControl.MyCustomProperty>`. It doesn't involve using an `ItemsControl`. It's a dependency property. Didn't you check out the link I provided?

Comment: Yes, I saw the link, but it still didn't work. If you want to see the code https://github.com/ofelipegodinho/SOposts/tree/master/CSharp/WPF/CollectionDependencyProperties , the only thing I did differently was to exchange Item for Button and initialize the PropertyMetadata

Comment: You should remove `new PropertyMetadata(new List<Button>())`. And where do you expect to see the buttons? You are adding them to a collection property but you don't display them somwhere. You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: It is not possible to remove `new PropertyMetadata (new List <Button> ())`, because `DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly` does not have an overload that accepts only 3 arguments (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty?view=net-5.0#methods). I expected to see the buttons inside `MyUserControl`, so I commented that I got displays using `ItemsControl`. But you are correct, I should probably ask a new question.

Comment: @FelipeGodinho: So replace it with just `new PropertyMetadata()`.